# Unable to implement a between statement in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

Hi I am implementing a simple application with Hibernate and HSQL. Hibernate however behaves very strange ! I want to query some entities in between tow values however only one entity is returned but not the whole list.

here is my method.

```
 @Override
    public List<ClientConnectionEntity> getConnectionBetween(long start, long end) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM com.cayetano.persistense.entities.ClientConnectionEntity c" +
                " WHERE c.connectionTime between :start and :end ")
                .setParameter("start", start)
                .setParameter("end", end);
        List<ClientConnectionEntity> list = query.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    } 




@Override
    public void saveConnection(ClientConnectionEntity entity) {


        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();


        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();


        session.persist(entity);


        transaction.commit();

        session.close();
    }



@Test
    public void returnsClientConnectionsBetweenTwoDates() {

        ClientConnectionEntity entity1 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
        entity1.setConnectionTime(1l);
        entity1.setClientBrowser("1");

        ClientConnectionEntity entity2 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
        entity1.setConnectionTime(2l);
        entity1.setClientBrowser("2");

        ClientConnectionEntity entity3 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
        entity1.setConnectionTime(2l);
        entity1.setClientBrowser("2");


        ClientConnectionEntity entity4 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
        entity1.setConnectionTime(4l);
        entity1.setClientBrowser("4");


        repository.saveConnection(entity1);
        repository.saveConnection(entity2);
        repository.saveConnection(entity3);
        repository.saveConnection(entity4);

        assertThat(repository.getConnections().size(),is(4)); // this one is Ok 

        List<ClientConnectionEntity> expected =  repository.getConnectionBetween(2l, 4l);

        assertThat(expected.size(), is(2));

    }
```

and the test fails ...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <2>
     but: was <1>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)
```

Comment: You also have some more serious issues. Not closing the `session` in a `finally` is a big no-no as exceptions will cause a resource leak. Also closing the session after querying will likely cause a `LazyInitializationException` later, when you try and access properties of the queried entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ClientConnectionEntity entity1 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
    entity1.setConnectionTime(1l);
    entity1.setClientBrowser("1");

    ClientConnectionEntity entity2 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
    entity1.setConnectionTime(2l);
    entity1.setClientBrowser("2");

    ClientConnectionEntity entity3 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
    entity1.setConnectionTime(2l);
    entity1.setClientBrowser("2");


    ClientConnectionEntity entity4 = new ClientConnectionEntity();
    entity1.setConnectionTime(4l);
    entity1.setClientBrowser("4");
```

You did a copy/paste and forgot to change the variables name

Comment: Ah, the old copy-pasta. Well spotted.

Comment: So what ? Copy paste is no the problem ... I don't see it there should be 4 entities with time in long value 1l,2l,2l,4l and I should get 2 entities when querying like this.  repository.getConnectionBetween(2l, 4l)

Comment: @Adio all your `setConnectionTime`and `setClientBrowser`are set on entity1

Comment: OMG I spend about an HOUR on this one :( THANK YOU VERY MUCH !